# OpenCv: size of images to create an xml training haartraining?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

[I read this post to create a custom xml file haartraining](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#w0a08ab4)

- positive and negative images must have the same dimensions (width x
  height)?
- positive images must have the same size as the negative ones?
- in createsamples and opencv_traincascade What should I put in the
  parameters -h and -w?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

negative samples can be any size, the training will select subwindows and scaled versions of the subwindows automatically (because maaaaany negative samples are needed). For each negative image you'll need a line with the path in a .txt file. If you want to use "hard samples" which exactly fit the detector size, you'll have to crop the negative images to the relevant region and resize them manually to fit the target size.

The positive samples can be any size, but you have to prepare a .txt file with information of where inside of the image the object is located. 
For example if the image is `C:\haartraining\positives\image00001.png` and a single object is at roi position `(x,y,width,height)` then your .txt file must contain the line `C:\haartraining\positives\image00001.png 1 x y width height`. This width/height can be any size (needn't be the same for each image), it will be scaled later by opencv_createsamples to the target size.

For haar training you'll need a .vec file instead of that .txt file and you can create the .vec file with opencv_createsamples binary. this binary has at least 3 different modes to create samples:

```
1. Just transform your positive images to a .vec file by scaling and formatting.
2. Create a lot of positive images by providing some background images, a single positive image and constraint about how the sample may be transformed/distorted.
3. Create Test images which can be used to test the training result, by placing positive images inside of some bigger scene background images.
```

I only have experience with `1.` so I can't help with the other ones. You just enter the positives text file and the target window size together with the number of positive images you have, and opencv_createsamples creates the .vec file which you'll need for training with opencv_trainingcascade.

In opencv_traincascade you must take care to provide good number for numPos and numNeg since in each stage you'll "lose" samples, which can be a bit confusing without experience. For example if your vec file contains 8000 positive images, you can't tell opencv_haartraining to use 8000 positive images in each stage, because with a minHitRate of for example 0.995 there might only be 7960 positive samples be left after the first stage (worst case). Same for negative samples, but there it's not so easy to tell how many samples you effectively HAVE...

afaik, width and height must be the same in createsamples and traincascade! It must be the minimum size that you want to detect objects after training, but it must be big enough to hold the relevant information. Maybe you have to test a bit until you find the optimum size. But unfortunately the size is quite limited because of memory problems during training. For example I couldn't train bigger than approx. 30x30. Afaik face detection was scientifically evaluated to produce good results for either 24x24 without or 20x20 with some tree-splits.

Please tell me whether this answers your question.

Comment: thank you so much, you've been very exhaustive.
but then, if the images can have different sizes
in createsamples and opencv_traincascade What should I put in the parameters -h and -w?

Comment: afaik, width and height must be the same in createsamples and traincascade! It must be the minimum size that you want to detect objects afte training, but it must be big enough to hold the relevant information. Maybe you have to test a bit until you find the optimum size. But unfortunately the size is quite limited because of memory problems during training. For example I couldn't train bigger than approx. 30x30. Afaik face detection was scientifically evaluated to produce good results for either 24x24 without or 20x20 with some tree-splits.